# Django - Filter select choices based on another selected element

Tags: python, django

I have two models that are related

```
class Filial(models.Model):
    descricao = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    empresa = models.ForeignKey(
        'BOXCFG.Empresa', related_name="filiais", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Empresa(models.Model):
    razao_social = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    logo = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=logo_directory_path, default='images/totvs.jpg')
```

I want to create a form that only shows Filial options that are related to the selected Empresa in a previous form field on the same page.

Is there an easy way to do this with Django?

Comment: There are a few ways to do this:

1. Use a `formset` of `Filial`s based on the selected `Empresa`. This would require you to select the `Empresa` first, then load a new page with the `Empresa` and `Filial formset`

2. Use an AJAX call to load a `form` (or `formset`) that loads based on the `Empresa` that was selected.

Comment: In case it helps, I am rather new to web programming and, therefore am not using Javascript or Ajax yet. As a result, I end up doing things in Django that aren't exactly the way I want but get the job done. I figure I can clean them up in the longer term, once I've got my base app done. For example, in your case, I might develop a template that presents a 'select Empresa' screen, bring the result back to Django and then follow up with a screen showing the Filial. It's not perfect but it gets the job done as I'm learning the technologies.

Comment: Empresa has many Filial or Filial has many Empresa? Tell me if I'm getting it wrong but don't you have model relation backwards?

Comment: Empresa has many Filial.

Comment: If I understand you, here's my approach: from the view you have empresa detail and a link to add filial, send the `id of empresa`, and in the form of filial create an `input hidden` with the sent empresa `id`. I use class bassed view `CreateView` with `get_context_data` to do this. The downside of this approach is that you need to declare all form fields mannually, not use `form.as_p` or similar. Hope is understandable and helps.